# Showing that every finite $T_1$-space is discrete

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Here's an exercise I'm trying to solve as I'm studying topology. Please let me know if my proof convinces you and feel free to otherwise criticise it.

**Proposition 1.** Every finite $T_1$-space is discrete.

To be fully precise, let me fix the definitions here.

**Definition**. A topological space $X$ is called $T_1$ iff given any two distinct points $x, y \in X$, both have neighbourhoods that do not contain each other i.e. there exist open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x \in U$, $y \in V$, $y \notin U$, and $x \notin V$.

**Definition.** A space $X$ is called discrete iff all of its subsets are open.

I will also assume the following lemmata.

**Lemma 1.** A space $X$ is $T_1$ iff all of its singleton subsets are closed.

**Lemma 2.** Finite unions of closed sets are closed.

*Proof attempt for Prop. 1*. Let $X$ be a finite $T_1$-space and let $U \subseteq X$ be an arbitrary subset. We need to show that $U$ is open i.e. that the complement of $U$ (which we denote $U^c$) is closed. As $X$ is finite, $U^c$ must have finitely many elements and must therefore be the union of finitely many singleton sets. By **Lemma 1**, we know that each of these singleton sets are closed as $X$ is a $T_1$-space. By the closure of closed sets under finite unions (**Lemma 2**), $U^c$ must be closed.

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/374070/737641) to the question you linked to does answer my question.

Comment: The proof looks good for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem**

A topological space is $T_1$ if and only if any singleton is closed.

**Corollary**

Any finite set of a $T_1$ space is closed.

Now if $X$ is finite then $X:=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$ so $X':=\{x_{i_1},...,x_{i_{n-1}}\}$ is closed for any $i_1,...,i_{n-1}\in\{1,...,n-1\}$ and so $X\setminus X'=\{x_{i_n}\}$ is open.